# Run specific part of Cypress test multiple times (not whole test)

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Is it possible to run specific part of the test in Cypress over and over again without execution of whole test case? I got error in the second part of test case and first half of it takes 100s. It means I have to wait 100s every time to get to the point where the error occurs. I would like rerun test case just few steps before error occurs. So once again, my question is: Is it possible to do in Cypress? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean like some portions inside 1 `it` block of you mean like there are multiple `it` blocks and you want to only run some specific `it` block?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't very clear. Because I use cucumber + cypress, I don't know how to describe it properly. Consider 1 Given() block, 10 And() blocks and in the 8th And() block there is an error. I want to rerun only 7th block and continue, not start from 1 Given block again. Do you know what I mean? @AlapanDas

Comment: any line of code can be run as many times as you need by using the iteration statements. btw, It will be much easier to provide a solution if you would share some context (your test code).

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround #1**

If you are using cucumber in cypress you can modify your scenario to a Scenario Outline that will execute Nth times with a scenario tag:

```
@runMe
Scenario Outline: Visit Google Page
  Given that google page is displayed
  Examples:
   | nthRun |
   | 1  |
   | 2  |
   | 3  |
   | 4  |
   | 100  |
```

After that run the test in the terminal by running through tags:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@runMe'
```

*Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor?activeTab=versions#running-tagged-tests*

**Workaround #2**

Cypress does have retry capability but it would only retry the scenario during failure. You can force your scenario to fail to retry it Nth times with a scenario tag:

In your **cypress.json** add the following configuration:

```
{
  "retries": {
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress run`
    // Default is 0
    "runMode": 99,
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress open`
    // Default is 0
    "openMode": 99
  }
}
```

*Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#How-It-Works*

Next is In your feature file, add an unknown step definition on the last step of your scenario to make it fail:

```
@runMe
Scenario: Visit Google Page
  Given that google page is displayed
  And I am an uknown step
```

Then run the test through tags:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@runMe'
```

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that doesn't require adding a change to the config file, you can pass retries as a param to specific tests that are known to be flakey for acceptable reasons.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Custom-Configurations

Meaning you can write (from docs)

````
describe('User bank accounts', {
  retries: {
    runMode: 2,
    openMode: 1,
  }
}, () => {
  // The per-suite configuration is applied to each test
  // If a test fails, it will be retried
  it('allows a user to view their transactions', () => {
    // ...
  }

  it('allows a user to edit their transactions', () => {
    // ...
  }
})```
````